# Two years of data with pre/post, need to figure out size of impact

Tags: effect-size, treatment-effect

I have 2 data sets: 2013-14 and 2014-15. Each year has pre and post data, measuring literacy. Sample size is 101 in one year and 93 in the other. I would like to determine if 2014-15 results were better or worse, and the size of this effect, pre to post. Does the nature of the distribution matter in picking a test? Mine are positively skewed for the most part.

Is effect size the right analysis to use? I'm looking at Klauer's effect size, using [this formula](http://www.psychometrica.de/effect_size.html).

Using the above calculator gives me a value of negative 0.26. How do I interpret this? Did 2014-15 had a slightly lower effect, pre-post, compared to 2013-14 pre-post?

I have not used effect sizes in the past and need to be explain it to a lay audience.